# How to make CONNECT call in iOS?

Tags: ios, http, nsurlsession

NSURLSession supports POST and GET; does it also support CONNECT?

If so, what is the exact syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSMutableURLRequest` to set whatever HTTP method you want

```
let session = NSURLSession()

guard let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com") else {
    fatalError("Error creating NSURL for http://www.google.com")
}

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "CONNECT"

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)

task.resume()
```